# C# WebSockets Multicast notifications asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I have a Asp.NET core application. `Startup.Configure()` mainly contains this code

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
{
    // If the request is a WebServerRequest, handle it as such ...
    if (httpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        ClientHandler h = new ClientHandler(httpContext);

        if (h.IsWebsockOpen)
        {
            await h.Handle();
        }
        else
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
    }

    // ... otherwise just hand the request to the next element in chain
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

Inside `h.Handle()` the client is supposed to register with a `ClientManager` which in turn multicasts that a new client has connected like this

```
public async Task Multicast<T>(List<ClientHandler> l, Msg<T> m)
{
    foreach (ClientHandler h in l)
    {
        if (h.IsWebsockOpen)
        {
            await h.webSocket.SendAsync(
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m.ToString()),
                System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                true,
                System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

I am now wondering if that is safe to do. I can imagine a scenario where two clients connect at the same time resulting in `h.webSocket.SendAsync` being called twice simultaneously, which is not allowed as said in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.sendasync?view=netframework-4.8

> Remarks
>   This operation will not block. The returned Task object will complete after the data has been sent on the WebSocket.
>
> Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each WebSocket object in parallel.

Wraping the `h.webSocket.SendAsync` in a `lock`-statement seems to be impossible due to the `await` keyword.

How can I make my code safe? Related questions are either not using WebSockets or they use different frameworks for which mechanisms apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a semaphore here, specifically [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8).  I'd suggest making a `SendAsync` method on your `ClientHandler` class and piping all requests via that - ie call it from your `Multicast` method.

The content of your `ClientHandler` would then be something like:

```
class ClientHandler() {
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _sendLock;
    public ClientHandler(HttpContext context) {
        _sendLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        //....
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string msg) {
        await _sendLock.WaitAsync();
        try {
            await webSocket.SendAsync( 
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg.ToString()),
                System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                true,
                System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        } finally {
            _sendLock.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

The `SemaphoreSlim` is `IDisposable`, so you'll need to take care of that, and its `WaitAsync` method has overloads for cancellation tokens and/or timeouts that might be appropriate for you to use.

Comment: No - each call from different places to `SendAsync` will await until they are given the semaphore, only one at a time will receive it and progress to awaiting the actual web socket send, then will release the semaphore for the next caller to `SendAsync`.  You can think of it as using a `lock { ... }` but it works for async/await. (I should mention, we use exactly this around our web socket implementation)